# Problems with FXMLLoader in javaFX tutorials from Oracle

Tags: javafx, fxml

Some time ago I started javafx tutorials from Oracle website. During doing this tutorial https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/fxml_tutorial.htm I encountered a problem. Here is a code:

1) fxml_example.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.net.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

<GridPane fx:controller="fxmlexample.FXMLExampleController"
xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10">
<fx:script>
    function handleSubmitButtonAction(){
    actiontarget.setText("Calling the JavaScript");
    }
</fx:script>
<padding>
    <Insets top="25" right="25" bottom="10" left="25" />
</padding>

<Text text="Welcome" GridPane.columnIndex="0"
    GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />

<Label text="User Name:" GridPane.columnIndex="0"
    GridPane.rowIndex="1" />

<TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />

<Label text="Password:" GridPane.columnIndex="0"
    GridPane.rowIndex="2" />

<PasswordField fx:id="passwordField"
    GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />

<HBox alignment="bottom_right" spacing="10"
    GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4">

    <Button text="Button" onAction="#handleSubmitButtonAction" />

</HBox>

<Text fx:id="actiontarget" GridPane.columnIndex="0"
    GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT"
    GridPane.rowIndex="6" />
</GridPane>
```

2) FXMLExample.java

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FXMLExample extends Application{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxml_example.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 275);

    stage.setTitle("FXML Welcome");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

3) FXMLExampleController.java

```
package application;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

public class FXMLExampleController {
    @FXML private Text actiontarget;

    @FXML protected void handleSubmitButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        actiontarget.setText("Sign in button pressed");
    }
}
```

And here is a listing of exceptions:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at         com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
at     com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$154(LauncherImpl.java:182)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/.../eclipse-workspace/FXMLExample/bin/application    /fxml_example.fxml:10

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:103)
at     javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:922)
at     javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.    java:971)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:220)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:744)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
at application.FXMLExample.start(FXMLExample.java:12)
at     com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(Launcher    Impl.java:863)
at     com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.jav    a:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:     fxmlexample.FXMLExampleController
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at     javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:920)
... 22 more
Exception running application application.FXMLExample
```

So, is something wrong with FXMLLoader? But what? And how to fix it?

Comment: Since you accepted the answer I assume your code is working now. Don't change the question and fix the error. (This would invalidate the accepted answer and turn your question into one where the error cannot be reproduced. That would make the question a candidate for closing (and probably the justified target of some downvotes).) I rolled back your edit for this reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your FXML sets the `fx:controller` to `fxmlexample.FXMLExampleController`, yet your package name is `application`, so the `fx:controller` value should be `application.FXMLExampleController` (or you could change your package name to `fxmlexample` to match the example code).

Comment: Ah, right.

I renamed package to fxmlexample. I will now update my post, because this doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Now I see that I mixed two solutions in one. I should use JavaScript function or FXMLExampleController.java, not both.

Comment: How can i solve this same issue if i am not using packages? what can i write here fx:controller=???